# WPF Drop Shadow Size

Tags: c#, wpf

As I understand, the BitmapEffects property in WPF is deprecated, so in order to simulate an outer glow effect, I have to use a drop shadow inside the Effects property.

The problem with this, is simply that there is no ShadowSize property that allows me to make the glow larger etc.

The relevant properties seem to be:

- BlurRadius - only affects the size of the *blur*
- Direction - changes
  direction not size
- Opacity - defaults at 100, so changing this doesn't
  make the glow more visible
- ShadowDepth - sets the distace away from
  the UIElement that the glow starts, but I need this to be 0 if I want
  to simulate a 'glow'

So it seems to me that none of these actually affect the shadow size. How then can I make a nice, big outer glow in WPF?

Answer (score 3):

The lack of outglow shader is VERY annoying. Microsoft really stuffed us here.

You have 3 options:

- Download a third party shader http://wpffx.codeplex.com/
- Write your own shader http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71617/Getting-Started-with-Shader-Effects-in-WPF
- Make do with the depreciated classes and the associated performance hit (they are software rendered - a BitmapCache can help greatly.)